# View content of a Stream in Visual Studio's QuickWatch window

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How do I view the content of a Stream in the QuickWatch window within Visual Studio?

**Update**

As per Daniel's answer I used the following code -

`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])stream.GetType().GetMethod("InternalGetBuffer", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(stream, null))`

Comment: Which Stream? is steram is text/binary/xml?

Comment: It's a MemoryStream containing JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the content of the `MemoryStream` without altering it when you can make some assumptions:

1. Your stream indeed is a `MemoryStream`
2. Your stream contains only string data
3. You know the encoding of that string, e.g. UTF8 or ASCII

If you *can* make these assumptions, you can use the following code in your Watch window:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])stream.GetType().GetMethod("InternalGetBuffer", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(stream, null))
```

Disclaimer:
This might have side effects I haven't thought of or might throw an exception in certain circumstances, so don't use this in production code.

Comment: This worked for me once I included the full namespace for Encoding and BindingFlags

Comment: Updated to include those namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's anything generic built in, since QuickWatch is not generally designed to affect the state of what's being watched, and reading from a stream inherently alters the internal state (e.g. the current position) - even assuming that the stream [can be read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread.aspx).

And even then, not all streams [support seeking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx), so reading from the stream would then make the read data unavailable for the actual program, with no means to recover that data.

---

In limited circumstances, if you construct the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a84386f.aspx) from a `byte` buffer, or if [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) is applicable, a watch on the `byte` buffer would be doable, rather than trying to watch the stream.